# How to scroll RecyclerView completely

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a RecyclerView and a RelativeLayout (as of 40dp height) below to it (which becomes visible based on a condition). When I call `rv_chat.smoothScrollToPosition(chatModelArrayList.size() - 1);`, the RecyclerView is showing its last item perfectly.

Now in this state, if the bottom RelativeLayout becomes visible then the last item in the RecyclerView hides a bit (40dp from bottom as the height of RelativeLayout) from bottom (goes under scroll).

To overcome this state, in the condition where the RelativeLayout becomes visible, I further call `rv_chat.smoothScrollToPosition(chatModelArrayList.size() - 1);` but as last item is visible already and only part of it is under scroll, `smoothScrollToPosition` does not do anything. So my question is that how to scroll a RecyclerView at bottom completely irrespective of which item is displaying at present?

Let me know if there is need of any further clarification in the above demonstration of my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add your layout file

Comment: you need to add ` android:layout_above="bottom_layout_id"` on receylerview tag and use parent of` Recylerview` is `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @parek, can you please give detail about what you want to say exactly.

Comment: @RajasekaranM, It is already inside a RelativeLayout and using the property. I think you misunderstood. If you read the demonstration in detail then you will find that it is having issue when my bottom layout becomes visible on certain conditions. The reason is that as RecyclerView is already scrolled to bottom and when screen visible area becomes shorter (due to the layout visibility), a part of the last item comes under scroll. I want to scroll down the RecyclerView fully after the condition to make last item visible completely.

Comment: Add layout file containing recyclerview